# EF Core Linq with Multiple Count Using the Same Column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am counting the total number of records based on a condition from the same column, basically, this is what I have now:

```cs
var checkTotal = await _dbRO.AllOpenExceptions
    .Where(x => x.ClientId == _user.ClientId)
    .CountAsync(x => x.ExceptionType == "Check");

var achTotal = await _dbRO.AllOpenExceptions
    .Where(x => x.ClientId == _user.ClientId)
    .CountAsync(x => x.ExceptionType == "ACH");
```

As you can see, I just need to count the number of records for ExceptionType column is "Check" vs. "ACH". Is there any way to combine these two separate queries into a single query?

I've tried group by with select but couldn't figure out the exact syntax. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `GroupBy`:

```cs
var totals = await _dbRO.AllOpenExceptions
    .Where(x => x.ClientId == _user.ClientId)
    .GroupBy(x => 1)
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
        CheckCount = g.Sum(x => x.ExceptionType == "Check" ? 1 : 0), 
        AchCount   = g.Sum(x => x.ExceptionType == "ACH"   ? 1 : 0) 
    )
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var checkTotal = totals?.CheckCount ?? 0;
var achTotal   = totals?.AchCount   ?? 0;
```

Comment: Svyatoslav Danyliv, this works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

We can group and filter data using the clientId and exceptionType and then convert it to a dictionary:

```
var totals = await _dbRO.AllOpenExceptions
                        .Where(x => x.ClientId == clientId && (x.ExceptionType == "ACH" || x.ExceptionType == "Check"))
                        .GroupBy(x => new { x.ClientId, x.ExceptionType })
                        .ToDictionaryAsync(
                              key => key.Key.ExceptionType,
                              value => value.Count(),
                              cancellationToken);
```

If you don't have a cancellation token, just get rid of it. And now you can access your total by key **ACH** or **Check**.

```
var achTotal = totals["ACH"];
var checkTotal = totals["Check"];
```

Going a bit further and avoiding some exceptions, you could even use the TryGetValue method:

```
totals.TryGetValue("ACH", out var achTotal);
totals.TryGetValue("Check", out var checkTotal);
```

##### Proof of concept

[image: Proof of concept]

Comment: Hi Pedro, with your code I got this EF core error:

The LINQ expression 'DbSet<AllOpenExceptions>()
    .GroupBy(x => new {
        ClientId = x.ClientId,
        ExceptionType = x.ExceptionType
     })
    .Where(x => x.Key.ClientId == ___user_ClientId_0 && x.Key.ExceptionType == "ACH" || x.Key.ExceptionType == "Check")' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Comment: I changed my answer, try again pls.

Comment: Pedro, the new error now is -- Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'collection'), StackTrace =>    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.ApplyProjection(Expression shaperExpression, ResultCardinality resultCardinality, QuerySplittingBehavior querySplittingBehavior)

Comment: Hmm, probably there's a piece of important information that you have not shared with us. I've created a PoC here, tested this and it's working perfectly. Can you share your model and some data from the db in your question?

Comment: Pedra, the answer below from Svyatoslav Danyliv worked for me. Thanks again!